# yii2, как показать проверенные значения в CheckboxList

Tags: php, yii2

У меня есть массив checkboxArray где я цыклом пробегаю и в него сохраняю все мои категории для вывода в chechbox

Массив checkboxCheckedArray здесь сохраняю выбранные элементы пользователем

Дальше я хочу показать уже выбранные элементы пользователю, но это не работает

```
$model = new RelationsCategory();
        $modelCategories = new Categories();
        $allCategories = $modelCategories->getAllCategories();
        $relations = $model->issetRelation($id);

        $checkboxArray = array();
        $checkboxCheckedArray = array();
        foreach ($allCategories as $category) {
            $checkboxArray[$category->id] = $category->name;
            foreach ($relations as $data) {
                if ($category->id == $data->id) {
                    $checkboxCheckedArray[$category->name] = $category->name;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        $model->checkbox = $checkboxCheckedArray;

        return $this->render('update', [
            'checkboxArray' => $checkboxArray,
            'model' => $model
        ]);
```

мой view file

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model backend\models\RelationsCategory */
/* @var $checkboxArray backend\modules\relationscategory\controllers\RelationscategoryController */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="relations-category-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'checkbox')->checkboxList($checkboxArray); ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

RelationsCategory model

```
class RelationsCategory extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $checkbox;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'relations_category';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['subcategory', 'category'], 'required'],
            [['subcategory', 'category'], 'integer'],
            [['checkbox'], 'each', 'rule' => ['integer']],
            [['category'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Categories::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['category' => 'id']],
            [['subcategory'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Subcategories::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['subcategory' => 'id']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'subcategory' => 'Подкатегория',
            'category' => 'Категория',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Gets query for [[Category0]].
     *
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getCategory0()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Categories::className(), ['id' => 'category']);
    }

    /**
     * Gets query for [[Subcategory0]].
     *
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getSubcategory0()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Subcategories::className(), ['id' => 'subcategory']);
    }

    public function issetRelation($subId)
    {
        return self::find()->andWhere(['and',
            ['subcategory' => $subId],
        ])->all();
    }
}
```

как показать проверенные значения в CheckboxList?

Comment: Вам нужно при загрузке страницы с вашей формой показать пользователю лист чек-боксов с галочками на некоторых чек-боксах?

Comment: да, именно это мне нужно

Answer (score 0):

Небольшой пример:

***Model***

```
class TestForm extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var array Some test check-box list
     */
    public $some_checkbox_list = [];

    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['some_checkbox_list'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'some_checkbox_list' => 'Some checkbox list',
        ];
    }

}
```

***View:***

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'login-form']); ?>

<?php
$checkBoxListData = [
    0 => 'Test 1',
    1 => 'Test 2',
    2 => 'Test 3'
];
?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'some_checkbox_list')->checkboxList($checkBoxListData) ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-11">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'login-button']) ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

***Controller:***

```
public function actionTest()
{
    $model = new TestForm();
    $model->some_checkbox_list = [1,2];
    return $this->render('test', ['model' => $model]);
}
```

В данном примере есть массив `$checkBoxListData`, который используется для вывода самого чек-бокс-листа, у этого массива есть ключи (0,1,2). Если полю модели `some_checkbox_list` присвоить массив необходимых ключей, то будут выбраны только те варианты, ключи которых были в массиве что был присвоен. То есть если присвоить полю массив [1,2], то чек-боксы будут стоять только у "Test2" и "Test3".

P.S. Именно массив ключей кстати попадает в поле при загрузке из POST/GET запроса, когда вы отправляете форму.